# How do I add skipped dates on Report?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I add skipped dates on my report so there is no gap in time, an example 
I have this:

```
1/1/16: 10 sales
1/3/16: 4 sales
1/7/16: 11 Sales
1/8/16: 8 Sales
```

I want this:

```
1/1/16: 10 sales
1/2/16: No sales
1/3/16: 4 sales
1/4/16: No Sales
1/5/16: No Sales
1/6/16: No Sales
1/7/16: 11 Sales
1/8/16: 8 Sales
```

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of which RDBMS you're using, a popular method is to either have a date table, or create a temporary table with dates in it, and join that table to whatever table has your data. For example,

```
SELECT [datetable].[date], [SalesTable].[NumberOfSales]
FROM [datetable]
LEFT JOIN [SalesTable] ON [SalesTable].[Date] = [datetable].[date]
```

will show you what you're looking for, assuming [datetable] contains every date.

Comment: I'm sorry for the basic questions but I am new to Visual Studios and everything that comes with it. Where exactly am I adding these lines? Thanks again for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest loop date-range via your programming code instead of SQL left join

Answer (score 0):

Its always best to use a calendar table while reporting. Create a calendar table with all the dates and formats. Then you can join the calendar table and result view to get all dates and values.